# How to update DataGrid table after some time

Tags: c#, .net, email, datagrid

I'm working on an application that reads emails, extracts data from them and prints them in `DataGrid` (as alerts or notifications). The data is stored in a DB.

**Here's the scenario:**
A new email with data arrives, if a new alert does not arrive within a specific time slot(say within 5 minutes) from the same customer, with the opposite result(e.g. 1st alert was FAIL, 2nd SUCCESS => negation), the alert in the `Datagrid` is just updated.

**Where is my problem:**
In the part where I want to update the alert, a new alert is added, which causes a duplicate and the table is confused. And it does not update when new negation alert arrives.

**NOTICE**:
My application is larger, to better demonstrate my problem, the example is in the consol application.
**But with a few modifications, the code is the same**

Here is my code:

> Method, which read and extract data

```
public void MailKitLib(EmailParser emailParser)
        {
                using (var client = new ImapClient())
                {
                    using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
                    {
                        client.Connect(emailParser.ServerName, emailParser.Port, emailParser.isSSLuse,
                            cancel.Token);
                   
                    
                    client.Authenticate(emailParser.Username, emailParser.Password, cancel.Token);

                   
                    var inbox = client.Inbox;
                    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);

                    Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Unread);

                    for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                        MyAlert alert = new MyAlert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.Subject, message.Subject);
                    if (!MyAlert.alerts.Any(x => x.Id.Equals(alert.Id)))
                    {
                       
                        
                        MyAlert.alerts.Add(alert);\\Think of it as a method that saves the object to the database 
                    }
                     CheckForUpdates(MyAlert.alerts[i]);
                }

            }
                client.Disconnect(true);
                
            }

    }
```

> Method checking for updates

```
 public void CheckForUpdates(MyAlert alert)
    {

    double result = 0;
   
    foreach (var item in MyAlert.alerts.Select(x => x.NameOfCustomer.Equals(alert.NameOfCustomer)))
    {
        
        
        if (item)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MyAlert.alerts.Count(); i++)
            {
               result = MyAlert.alerts[i].Date.Minute - alert.Date.Minute;
                Console.WriteLine("Result of:" + MyAlert.alerts[i].NameOfCustomer + " " +
                                    "and" + " " + alert.NameOfCustomer + " " + "is:" + result);


                if (result > 0 && result <= 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You HAVE TO UPDATE this" + " " + MyAlert.alerts[i].NameOfAlert);
                    MyAlert.alerts[i].NameOfAlert = "UPDATED";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You DON'T have to UPDATE this:" + " " + MyAlert.alerts[i].NameOfAlert);
                   
                }
            }
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Wave:" + MyAlert.alerts.Count);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I figured this out with DB

```
 public double GetInterval(DateTime a, DateTime b)
        {
            return a.Subtract(b).TotalMinutes;
        }
        public void FindUpdate(Alert newAlert, Alert matchAlert)
        {

            //If new Alerts arrives from same customer with same problem till five 5 minutes
            if (dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Email.Equals(newAlert.Email) && x.Problem.NameOfAlert.Equals(newAlert.Problem.NameOfAlert))
                &&
                GetInterval(newAlert.Date, matchAlert.Date) > 0 && GetInterval(newAlert.Date, matchAlert.Date) <= 5)
            {
                //Find that Alert, and update his variables from alert, else save new alert
                var item = dAOAlert.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email.Equals(newAlert.Email) && x.Problem.NameOfAlert.Equals(newAlert.Problem.NameOfAlert));
                dAOAlert.Update(item, newAlert);
                dAOAlert.Delete(newAlert);
                LoadAlertGrid();
            }
        }
```

And this is how I have used this in Main method

```
for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                            GetBodyText = message.TextBody;
                            Problem problem = new Problem(message.MessageId);
                            if (!dAOProblem.GetAll().Any(x => x.Message_Id.Equals(problem.Message_Id)))
                            {
                                dAOProblem.Save(problem);
                                Alert alert = new Alert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.From.ToString(), 1, problem.Id);
                                if (!dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Id_MimeMessage.Equals(alert.Id_MimeMessage)))
                                {
                                    dAOAlert.Save(alert);
                                    foreach (var item in dAOAlert.GetAll())
                                    {
                                        FindUpdate(alert, item);
                                    }
                                    LoadAlertGrid();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   
                                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
                                }

                            }

                        }
```